# iTextSharp - Continuing ordered list on second page with a number other than '1'

Tags: itext

I am fairly new to iTextSharp.  I create PDFs by adding variable data (text/barcodes/images) to existing PDF documents/templates (think boiler plate).  Most commonly, I have to place various sections of text in specific places.  I know how to create an ordered list, but I have come across a situation where the list begins with #1 on the first page and then #2-4 on the top of the second page. I use two different templates for p1 and p2.

I am currently creating the document by creating ColumnTexts, placing SimpleColumns with specific coordinates, and then placing phrases inside. I am not sure if this is the best way or not, so I am open for alternative solutions.

I have checked out several places including http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/83/lists-with-itextsharp but I see nothing that describes how to start a list at a number other than '1'.  None of the 6 overloads provide a parameter for starting number.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two answers to your question. The first one is to point you to the official documentation. There is a method [`setFirst()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/List.html#setFirst(int)) that (I quote) *sets the number that has to come first in the list*.

You are using the C# port of iText, so if you want the list to start counting at 10, you need to do something like:

```
list.First = 10;
```

The second answer takes more time, but it is probably the better one.You don't need two `List` objects, one for the first page and one for the second page. It's better to add the `List` to a `ColumnText` object and then distribute the column over two pages.

Take a look at the [ListInColumn](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/ListInColumn) example. It takes an existing PDF (with the text "Hello World Hello People") and it adds a list using `ColumnText`: [list_in_column.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/list_in_column.pdf)

[image]

This is how it's done:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
List list = new List(List.ORDERED);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list.add("...");
}
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(stamper.getOverContent(1));
ct.addElement(list);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(250, 400, 500, 806);
ct.setSimpleColumn(rect);
int status = ct.go();
if (ColumnText.hasMoreText(status)) {
    ct.setCanvas(stamper.getOverContent(2));
    ct.setSimpleColumn(rect);
    ct.go();
}
stamper.close();
```

To add the content on the first page, I use:

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(stamper.getOverContent(1));
```

You are probably using similar code.

The content is added using the line:

```
int status = ct.go();
```

If not all the content was added, I change the canvas to add the rest of the content on the second page:

```
ct.setCanvas(stamper.getOverContent(2));
```

The rest of the code is pretty standard.

I think the `setCanvas()` method is the missing piece in your puzzle, although in your case, you'll need:

```
ct.Canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(2);
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno.  I was not aware you could distribute column over two pages.  I thought that, because of the specific coordinates given, it was limited to the current page.  If you could throw a small Java example, that would help. Thanks!

Comment: Done! The missing piece in your puzzle was probably `ct.Canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(2);`

Comment: Again, Thanks! I was unfamiliar with setCanvas(). I VERY MUCH appreciate your time, clarity, and thorough answer!

Comment: @rcurrydev The question is a good candidate for one of the next releases of [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html)